# LIghtning Component Window size update

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have an issue with the lightning window size. I have 2 sections in my lightning component and at a time only one of them is visible. When the app first loads, only the first section is visible and the height of the window gets set to the height of that section. When the second section is made visible, since its contents are larger, some of the content at the bottom is not visible. Earlier I could update the window size by using `ui:updatesize` method, but since that is not possible anymore, is there any workaround for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121137/summer-16-lightning-component-container-not-scrolling ?